# Scroll bar in xgterm?

Tags: linux, terminal

Does anyone know how to add or activate a scroll feature in xgterm? It is a bit obnoxious to not be able to scroll around the rest of the terminal.

Comment: Perhaps you could use another terminal that does support scrolling?

Comment: I need to use xgterm for iraf

Answer (score 0):

To activate the scrollbar in `xgterm`, run it as:

```
xgterm -sb
```

Or set it via the `~/.Xresources` file:

```
*VT100.scrollBar: True
```

Credit: information found via [mailing list](ftp://iraf.noao.edu/ftp/web/sites/list2/0500.html) and [an iraf user's page](http://www.physics.uci.edu/~barth/astro-computing/irafsetup.html).